# ipcapi parameter usage

Tags: go-ethereum, ipc, interfaces

I initialize a node on my private test net passing only the `eth` interface in the `ipcapi` parameter expecting that I won't have access in the other interfaces such as admin etc.. However, when I attach a terminal to the node I have access to all apis. What is the puprpose of the `ipcapi` parameter then?

this is how I initialize start the node listening to ipc connections

`geth --datadir ~/ethereum/localnode --ipcapi eth --networkid 1234 console`

Comment: What command are you running to attach to the node?

Comment: @RichardHorrocks I'm using this command ```geth attach ipc:~/ethereum/geth.ipc```